# Changing bottom and top values in a CSS transition on click

Tags: css

I have a `div` with a `fixed` position that is supposed to slide up/down on click. I'm trying to get this to work with a smooth CSS `transition` but it only jumps up/down when clicked. I'm probably missing something obvious here but can't figure out what.

Any ideas?

**[I've created a demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/8d19f59q/)**

**My CSS:**

```
  .wrapper {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 30px;
      top: initial;
      background: green;
      width: 100%;
      height: 20px;
      -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
      -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
      -o-transition: all 1s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
      transition: all 1s ease;
  }
  .wrapper.slide-up {
      top: 0px;
      bottom: initial;
  }
  .wrapper.slide-down {
      top: auto;
      bottom: 36px;
  }
```

**My JS:**

```
  var wrapper = $('.wrapper');

  $(wrapper).click(

  function () {
      if (wrapper.hasClass('slide-up')) {
          wrapper.addClass('slide-down').removeClass('slide-up');
      } else {
          wrapper.removeClass('slide-down').addClass('slide-up');
      }
  });
```

Comment: Does this help? http://jsfiddle.net/8d19f59q/10/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `top` and `bottom` interchangeably. You need to have one style you need to change.

For example:

```
.wrapper.slide-up {
  top: 0px;
}
.wrapper.slide-down {
   top: calc(100% - 36px);
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8d19f59q/13/)

You can use the `calc` css function to work out exactly what you need.

```
top: calc(100% - 36px);
```

But you need to make sure that when you're doing transitions, you keep it to one element that you need to change. So `top` will give it the animation when you have two different `top` values, but when you introduce `bottom` when it's not set, it will just 'jump'.

Be careful when using `calc()` as it isn't fully supported in older browsers:

[Can I use - Calc()](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc)

Comment: It would be better to apply `top: 100%;` and pull the element back up into view. In this case: `margin-top: -20px;` (the height of the element).

Comment: I was adding more to the answer just as you said that :) @EdB

Comment: Nice. Treading carefully when using `calc` though as it still has some [known issues](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) ;) @BeatAlex

Answer (score 3):

I think the reason is in moving from `0` to `auto` value. You must specify the numbers in both cases, see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8d19f59q/2/).

I changed CSS only: you can calculate the position in both classes based on `top` only

```
.wrapper.slide-up {
    top: 0px;
}
.wrapper.slide-down {
    top: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

Maybe it won't work for your business case but for this example it does.

By the way `20px` in `calc(100% - 20px)` is the height of the block.

Answer (score 2):

Check this fiddle if it suit your needs: https://jsfiddle.net/8d19f59q/12/

```
top: calc(100vh - 20px - 36px);
```

this made the trick...

Comment: is `top:calc(100vh - 56px);` the same thing?

Comment: Use `calc` with a lot of caution! Safari (on both Mac and iOS) doesn't support viewport units (`vh`, `vw`, etc) yet.

Comment: yes @jbutler483 i wrote in that way to make it more easy to read, highlighting that 20px is the height of his div, and 36px the distance from bottom that he wanted.